# how can I relate values of generic type parameters in java Map interface?

Tags: java, generics, types, dictionary

I don't think the title of the question will be clear, but the idea is simple.

Suppose I have a Map type variable.

```
Map<K,V> myMap;
```

but I want to establish a relation between K and V. for example, I'd like to say that
this Map relates Sets of some class to objets of that class. Something like:

```
Map<Set<T>, T> myMap;
```

but not for a specific type T. I'd like this Map to accept entries like

```
(Set<String>, String),
(Set<Integer>, Integer)
...
```

Is there a possible declaration for myMap that allows me to have this behavior? Please let me know if I'm explaining myself wrongly or if I have a previous conceptual error.

Comment: Are you expecting that after putting an empty `Set<Integer>` in followed by an empty `Set<String>`, that an empty `Set<Integer>` will be unmapped or return a `String` (/throw a `ClassCastException`)?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is not possible with Java generics. If Java allowed *higher order* type parameters, then one could have defined `Map` something like:

```
public interface Map<V<>> {  // here V<> is my hypothetical syntax for a 
                             // type parameter which is itself generic...
    <K>
    V<K> put(K key, V<K> value);
    ...
}
```

instead of the actual `java.util.Map`:

```
public interface Map<K, V> {
    V put(K key, V value);
    ...
}
```

You can see that the problem is that `K` is declared once for the whole class and not for each call to `.put()`.

**Enough fantasizing, so what can you do?** I think the best is to create a `Map<Set<?>, Object>` and wrap it as a private member. Then you are free to create your own `put()` and `get()` which take into account the intended "relation" between types:

```
class SpecialMap {
    private Map<Set<?>, Object> map = ...;

    public <T>
    T put(Set<T> key, T value) {
        return (T) map.put(key, value);
    }

    public <T>
    T get(Set<T> key) {
        return (T) map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't seem like a good diea, because each `Set<T>` is always not equal to another `Set<T>` even if of the same type - using Sets as keys is more or less useless.

That said, you don't need to define a new class - you can require a method to accept such a map:

```
public static <T> void process(Map<Set<T>, T> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<Set<T>, T> entry : map) {
        Set<T> key = entry.getKey();
        T value = entry.getValue();
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with generics to have the compiler verify a different `T` for each `put()` call.  In other words, you **can't** have the *same* map and do:

```
myMap.put(new HashSet<String>(), "foo");
myMap.put(new HashSet<Integer>(), 1);
```

If you need this then you may have to store `<Object>` and do the verification yourself using `instanceof` or some other hack.

Now, you can definitely do something like:

```
public class MyMap<T> extends HashMap<Set<T>, T> {
    ...
```

Then you can do:

```
MyMap<String> myMap = new MyMap<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
myMap.put(set, "foo");
```

Remember that the key has to have a valid `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods which might be expensive with a `Set`.

Comment: nice! I didn't think of creating a named class to solve this. Don't worry about performance issues, the Set thing was just an example, my use case is different.

Comment: This still forces you to put key-value pairs of the same type. As I understand, the OP want to be able to put key-value pairs of different types in a single map wherein the value has the same type as the set of the key. The type has not to be definied on the class, but on the individual methods.

Comment: As far as i understand the Map he wants can contain both String and Integer entries but the mapping need to match. So Set of Integer to Integer and Set of String to String, but the same map can contain both types.

Comment: How would you want to look up values? Or is it for storage and iteration only?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve compile-time checking with Java generics. However it's quite simple at runtime. Just right a short decorator:

```
public class FancyTypeMapDecorator implements Map<Set<? extends Object>, Object> {

    final Map<Set<? extends Object>, Object> target;

    public FancyTypeMapDecorator(Map<Set<? extends Object>, Object> target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(Set<? extends Object> key, Object value) {
        final Class<?> keyElementType = key.iterator().next().getClass();
        final Class<?> valueType = value.getClass();
        if (keyElementType != valueType) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Key element type " + keyElementType + " does not match " + valueType);
        }
        return target.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends Set<? extends Object>, ? extends Object> m) {
        for (Entry<? extends Set<? extends Object>, ? extends Object> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    //remaining methods are simply delegating to target

}
```

Here's how it works:

```
final Map<Set<? extends Object>, Object> map =
    new FancyTypeMapDecorator(new HashMap<Set<? extends Object>, Object>());

Set<? extends Object> keyA = Collections.singleton(7);
map.put(keyA, 42);

Set<? extends Object> keyB = Collections.singleton("bogus");
map.put(keyB, 43);
```

Second `put` throws an exception.

However both the implementation (and I don't even mean that it will fail for empty `Set` as a key) and usage/API triggers an alarm bell... Do you really want to deal with such a structure? Maybe you need to rethink your problem? What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't think you want to match the exact runtime implementation type.

Comment: You're right, the OP can always use `valueType.isAssignableFrom(keyElementType)` or the other way around - depending on the requirements.